# How to get OpenGL man pages on Ubuntu as in "man glRotate"?

Tags: opengl, manpage

When on MacOSX, "man glRotate" brings up the glRotate manpage.

On ubuntu, with manpages-dev and manpages-posix-dev insatlled, "man glRotate" doesn't bring up the glRotate manpage (though I can build and compile gl apps).

What am I missing? How do I setup this up?

Comment: hopefully the man pages will be in the next ubuntu release:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/32042

read the comments to find a way to manually install them

Comment: "man glRotate" works just fine for me!    ...I'm typing it into the google search bar, does that change anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine the Khronos [OpenGL-Refpages repository](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Refpages) with [the `PKGBUILD` script](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/opengl-man-pages) from [the Arch `opengl-man-pages` package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/opengl-man-pages/).

```
# $Id$
# Maintainer: AndyRTR <andyrtr@archlinux.org>

pkgname=opengl-man-pages
pkgver=20170404
_commit=03552a8094ae3017e0b8b2ad44c602f81c03e848
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="OpenGL Man Pages"
arch=('any')
url="https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Refpages"
license=('custom')
# OpenGL 4.x (current) API and GLSL pages - libxslt' 'docbook-xsl'
# OpenGL 3.x and older 'w3c-mathml2' 'docbook-mathml'
makedepends=('libxslt' 'docbook-xsl' 'w3c-mathml2' 'docbook-mathml' 'git')
source=(${pkgname}::git+https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenGL-Refpages#commit=$_commit
        'LICENSE')
sha256sums=('SKIP'
            'a7b2f6669d7ead91dcaf5a03620cdf9d37c54d83fd1899b4ef84683c7e6d4024')
# gl2.1 = OpenGL 2.1 (including fixed functionality)
# es3   = OpenGL ES 3.x (will always be the latest ES, currently 3.2)
# gl4   = OpenGL 4.x (current) API and GLSL pages
_mandirs=(gl4 es3 gl2.1)

pkgver() {
  date +%Y%m%d
}

build() {
  export WD=`pwd`
  xmlcatalog --create --noout \
    --add public "-//W3C//DTD MathML 2.0//EN" "file:///usr/share/xml/w3c/mathml2/mathml2.dtd" \
    --add public "-//W3C//DTD MathML//EN" "file:///usr/share/xml/w3c/mathml2/mathml2.dtd" \
    --add system "http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML2/dtd/mathml2.dtd" "file:///usr/share/xml/w3c/mathml2/mathml2.dtd" \
    mathml2.cat
  export XML_CATALOG_FILES="$WD/mathml2.cat /etc/xml/catalog"

  for manpages in ${_mandirs[@]}; do
    cd "${srcdir}/${pkgname}/${manpages}"
    for file in gl*.xml; do
      xsltproc --noout --nonet /usr/share/xml/docbook/xsl-stylesheets-*/manpages/docbook.xsl ${file}
    done
  done
}

package() {
  install -d "${pkgdir}/usr/share/man/man3"
  for manpages in ${_mandirs[@]}; do
    cd "${srcdir}/${pkgname}/${manpages}"
    install -m644 *.3G "${pkgdir}/usr/share/man/man3/"
  done
  # license
  install -D -m644 "${srcdir}/LICENSE" "${pkgdir}/usr/share/licenses/${pkgname}/LICENSE"
}
```

I had to install some extra packages on my Debian Stretch box to build the documentation:

```
sudo apt-get install xsltproc docbook-xsl docbook-xsl-ns w3-dtd-mathml docbook-mathml
```

Comment: Note that this package seems to have last been updated in 2009.

Comment: @Ruslan: Updated to use the OpenGL-Refpages repository.

Comment: I tried to download the package (_Download From Mirror_ link in the Arch package page) only to notice that many of these man pages are badly formatted. See e.g. `man /path/to/glTexStorage2DMultisample.3G.gz`. And if you compare it with Ubuntu's `opengl-4-man-doc` referenced in the answer by Ciro, you'll see that Ubuntu ones are nice (checked the package for Trusty). Dunno where Ubuntu takes them from though.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo apt-get install opengl-4-man-doc opencl-1.2-man-doc
```

contains many man pages, e.g.:

```
man glDrawArrays
```

but it does not contain `man glRotate`. I think this is because the deprecated immediate APIs are not included.

`apt-file search glRotate` shows a few hits, but they don't seem "official".

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: `gluOrtho2D` also not found.

Comment: @helal likely because it is not part of the OpenGL API but rather of the GLU library. Unfortunately it is not packaged with freeglut-dev apparently, freeglut is the main Linux implementation. Let me know if you find a package that contains it.

Comment: I invite you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771076/how-to-make-a-3d-window-for-drawing-3d-points-in-c-using-opengl-functions

Comment: @helal suggestion: when asking, say what happened when you ran your code, and say what you would expect to happen instead. I urge you to use either of these tutorials: https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL or https://github.com/opengl-tutorials/ogl

Comment: how about GLX? is there a package for it as well?